# Cocoa: Can NSArrayController be subclassed to provide custom "Controller Key"s?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, subclassing

And if so, **how?**

This seems like a very useful thing to be able to do but I can't for the life of me figure it out or find any info on the net!

The specific situation I have in mind is I have two adjacent tables, the left initially contains a list of names, then I want "move left" and a "move right" button to move names from one table to the other.

I thought an elegant solution to this problem would be to use one array controller with two Controller Keys "arrangedLeftObjects" and arrangedRightObjects"

I'm going crazy here! Can someone please shed some light. I'll post example code on request.

Many thanks

**EDIT: initial attempts**

The NSArrayController subclass is implemented (so far) thusly:

```
@interface LeftRightArrayController : NSArrayController {
    NSArray * leftObjects;
}

-(NSArray *)leftObjects;
-(void)setLeftObjects:(NSArray *)newLeftObjects;
@end


@implementation LeftRightArrayController

-(NSArray *)leftObjects {
    return leftObjects;
}

-(void)setLeftObjects:(NSArray *)newLeftObjects {
    leftObjects = newLeftObjects;
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    [self setLeftObjects:[NSArray arrayWithArray:[self arrangedObjects]]];  
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}

@end
```

And the data provided to the controller:

```
[myArrayController addObserver:myArrayController forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:0 context:NULL];

NSString *myKey = [NSString stringWithString:@"name"];
NSDictionary *myNewDictionary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"date1" forKey:myKey];

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNewDictionary1, nil];

[myArrayController setContent:myArray];
```

This code works when I only bind to "Left Right Array Controller.arrangedObjects.name"
But breaks as soon as I attempt to  bind to "Left Right Array Controller.leftObjects.name"

Comment: Post an example of what you've already tried.

Comment: I've put some code up. It just seems like custom controller keys would be such a general useful thing to be able to do and I've seen no mention of it anywhere so I've become suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this. You should always use one `NSArrayController` per table view. In your case, you should have two backing arrays, one for the left objects and one for the right objects.

You should then bind each table view to the appropriate array via its own array controller.

You should then implement a separate controller to manage the transfer of data between the arrays, by either manipulating the arrays directly using KVO-compliant accessors or by using the various insert/remove methods of `NSArrayController`.

Comment: Seems like a ridiculous number of array controllers for what could (in my potentially naive opinion) be achieved with just one and couple of custom keys.

Comment: Say I was CRAZY, and wanted to do it my way, could I? Can it be done? And why is it so undesirable?

Comment: Because that's not how array controllers work. You should always have one array controller per table view. That's how they are designed to work. I don't think two array controllers instead of one is "crazy". You shouldn't subclass if you don't have to. Just create a lightweight custom controller to do the array shifting and then use the native array controllers to handle table display.

Comment: You could technically subclass `NSArrayController` and implement custom keys, but what's the point? It just creates needless complication.

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me that one controller per table is sensible (in fact I have just managed to make such a two-controller system work). Can you shed any light on how one would go about implementing custom keys (for if I have any other perverse ideas)?